# How does one tell u-boot to tell the Linux kernel which runlevel to boot to?

Tags: linux, bootloader, runlevel

I would like to order u-boot to enter a specific runlevel lower than the one the system boots to. How does one accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of digging before and after my question, I discovered that it's as simple as appending the number of the runlevel onto the end of the environment variable bootargs.

For instance, to enter into runlevel 3:

```
setenv bootargs ${bootargs} 3
```

and you can use

```
printenv bootargs
```

before and after to check your changes.

I found a huge hint for this at http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/14818.html